# How to delete part of a string after a specific character, on mutiple rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with the batting stats of all National League players from the 2020 season. When I imported the .csv file there was a bit of a formatting issue specifically with the player names

`Ronald Acuna Jr.\acunaro01`

I obviously would like to get rid of everything after the name (starting with the '') for all of the players spanning the 345 row table.

Some players may also be noted down as

`Tony Wolters*\wolteto01`

or

`Pablo Sandoval#\sandopa01`

I've been scouring throughout the internet and haven't exactly been able to find the right answer, this is as close as I've come to maybe having an idea of a solution.

```
UPDATE NLHITTERS
SET Name = REPLACE(Name, '%\_________', ' ')
WHERE Name LIKE '%\_________';
```

Comment: Does the `.` belong to the name in `'Ronald Acuna Jr.\acunaro01'` or not, i.e. should that be `'Ronald Acuna Jr.'` or `Ronald Acuna Jr'`? If the `.` is part of the name, is any `.` in that position part of the name or only after certain words (strings)?

Comment: @stickybit honestly for the sake of simplicity I'll take out `.` form that and any other names that have them. From eyeballing the table it seems to only be at the end of Jr's.

So it would be `Ronald Acuna Jr`

Comment: Starting with the `'('`.  I don't see any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below will update the name column if the char \ is found (INSTR > 0) and get the first char up to the location of \ and minus 1 char (. or # or *).

```
UPDATE NLHITTERS
SET Name = SUBSTR(Name, 0, INSTR(Name, "\")-1 )
WHERE INSTR(Name, "\") > 0;

 Result:
 name
Ronald Acuna Jr
Tony Wolters
Pablo Sandoval
```

See example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9a7be/9

Comment: Wow, many thanks, this worked. i'm going to internalize this and try to understand your thought process. Very clever solution, thanks for the help. I'm brand new at this and trying my best to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get everything before a certain character, I would recommend `substring_index()`:

```
update t
    set name = substring_index(name, '\\')
    where name like '%\\%';
```

Note:  I'm assuming that you need to use `\\` to get a backslash in the string.